# jQuery .each with $post to send value to external var not working

Tags: jquery, post, each

I'm trying to use the .each to add data for each time it loops to abilitiesExtra, but at the moment it doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why.

Where I think it's going wrong somehow:

```
  var abilitiesExtra = (0 * 1);
        $(".iconDiv").each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":empty") === false) {
                //alert("Hello");
                var ability = $(this).children("img").first().attr("class");
                $.post('PHP/getAbilityCost.php', {
                    ability: ability
                }, function (dataTwo) {
                    abilitiesExtra = (dataTwo * 1) + abilitiesExtra;
                });
            }
        });
       alert(abilitiesExtra);
```

The surrounding code:

```
 if (oneIsEmpty === "false") {
        var abilitiesCost = (0 * 1);
        var attack = $("#attack").val();
        var speed = $("#speed").val();
        var minRng = $("#minRng").val();
        var maxRng = $("#maxRng").val();
        var defense = $("#defense").val();
        var hitPoints = $("#hitPoints").val();
        var size = $("#size").val();
        $.post('PHP/getNoraCost.php', {
            attack: attack
            , speed: speed
            , minRng: minRng
            , maxRng: maxRng
            , defense: defense
            , hitPoints: hitPoints
            , size: size
        }, function (data) {
            abilitiesCost = (data * 1) + abilitiesCost;
        });
        var abilitiesExtra = (0 * 1);
        $(".iconDiv").each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":empty") === false) {
                var ability = $(this).children("img").first().attr("class");
                $.post('PHP/getAbilityCost.php', {
                    ability: ability
                }, function (dataTwo) {
                    abilitiesExtra = (dataTwo * 1) + abilitiesExtra;
                    console.log(abilitiesExtra); //gives the right number
                });
            }
        });
        //alert(abilitiesExtra) is always 0 now
        abilitiesCost = abilitiesExtra + abilitiesCost;
        $("#totalNoraCostD p").empty();
        $("#totalNoraCostD p").append(abilitiesCost);
    }
```

Comment: `abilitiesExtra = ($.parseInt(dataTwo) * 1) + $.parseInt(abilitiesExtra);` check it

Comment: I got following error doing that:
Uncaught TypeError: $.parseInt is not a function
    at Object.success (index.js:179)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: console.log(dataTwo); check this i think it's not coming as a number or string. it's coming as an object

Comment: The console log just outputs the right number. Let me add the surrounding code as well!

Comment: what's the output? can you show by an screenshot?

Comment: The output is just the number, e.g: 4 
(I updated original post)

Comment: The ajax calls are asynchronous. When you call `$.post()` it just sends the ajax request. The lines that come after the call to `$.post()` are executed right away. Later, when the ajax calls return, the callback functions are executed.

Comment: So I should change it to an $.ajax and set async: false than?

Comment: You should never set `async` to false. It is bad practice. It locks up the entire browser during the call (and it's just lazy programming). Besides, if you make the calls synchronous, they will not be all made at the same time. Instead, the first one has to return before the second is made, and so on.

Comment: I also found out it's depreciated, so it didn't work anyhow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax calls are asynchronous. When you call `$.post()`, it just sends the ajax request. The lines that come after the call to `$.post()` are executed right away. Later, when the ajax call returns, the callback function is executed.

The [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) function returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR) object, which is a [`Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) object. You can put all the `jqXHR` objects in an array, and then use [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to execute a callback when the last ajax call has returned.

```
if (!oneIsEmpty) {
    var abilitiesCost = 0;
    var abilitiesExtra = 0;

    var costJqXhr = $.post('PHP/getNoraCost.php', {
        attack: $("#attack").val(),
        speed: $("#speed").val(),
        minRng: $("#minRng").val(),
        maxRng: $("#maxRng").val(),
        defense: $("#defense").val(),
        hitPoints: $("#hitPoints").val(),
        size: $("#size").val()
    }, function(data) {
        abilitiesCost += (data * 1);
    });

    // This makes the ajax calls, creating an array of the jqXhr objects.
    var jqXhrs = $(".iconDiv:not(:empty)").map(function() {
        return $.post('PHP/getAbilityCost.php', {
            ability: $(this).children("img:first").attr("class")
        }, function(dataTwo) {
            abilitiesExtra += (dataTwo * 1);
        });
    });

    jqXhrs.push(costJqXhr);

    // This executes the callback when the last ajax call has returned.
    $.when.apply($, jqXhrs).then(function() {
        $("#totalNoraCostD p").html(abilitiesCost + abilitiesExtra);
    });
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8spkdgen/)

Comment: While the code runs without errors now it just returns 0 for both abilitiesCost and abilitiesExtra. So it's still the same issue. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: @Tibout - There were two mistakes in the code that caused the array to always be empty. (First, I missed putting `return` in the callback for `$.map()`, and second I had `.add()` when it should be `.push()`.) I also added a jsfiddle that shows it working.

Comment: Hey, it almost seems to work now!
The only problem I'm having is if all iconDivs are empty it's not working (and it still should), I tried to play around with all of this a bit, but couldn't get it.

Comment: @Tibout - Did you change `.add()` to `.push()`? I mentioned it in my previous comment, and it was correct in the jsfiddle, but I guess I hadn't updated the code in my answer.

Comment: That was it, I overlooked it as I noticed you had changed the return! Thanks so so much!